# 20.04: Forge Server not working

Tags: java, minecraft

We appear to be missing one or more essential library files in Ubuntu 20.04 on a [vps][1] machine rented from [contabo][2] running 8gb ram on 4 cores.

```
You will need to add them to your server before FML and Forge will run successfully.java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.run(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:52)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.main(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:34)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: My bad, i forgot to add the library folder to the actual server :) EPIC GAMER MOVES

Answer (score 0):

I Have the same problem. I solve using this comand:

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

and choosing this version : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/bin/java   1081      modo manual
You can get more info in this link :
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-java-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 0):

Per OP's comments:

> My bad, i forgot to add the library folder to the actual server :) EPIC GAMER MOVES